# Scoped service added is producing null error over the same request within middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating a piece of custom middleware that is going to used for telemetry purposes. This middleware is going to have a service that it uses to keep track of the different logs generated by my API, and once the request response is triggered it'll send off the traces to AppInsights.

The Invoke method of the middleware looks like this:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            
            _telemetryService.InitNewEvent();
            _telemetryService.Add("path", context.Request.Path, null); // Add works here
            await _next(context);
            _telemetryService.Add("statusCode", context.Response.StatusCode, null); // Add throws null error here
            _telemetryService.SendEvent(context.Response);
        }
```

Telemetry Service Excerpt

```
public class TelemetryService
    {
        private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
        
        private List<TelemetryTrace> _currentTelemetryEventData;
        private Dictionary<string, string> _finalisedTelemetryEventData;
        
        private string _eventName;
        private string _apiName = "pmapi";
        
        public TelemetryService(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        public void InitNewEvent()
        {
            _currentTelemetryEventData = new List<TelemetryTrace>();
            Console.WriteLine("New telemetry event inited");
        }
        
        public void Add(string key, object data, SeverityLevel? severityLevel)
        {
            _currentTelemetryEventData.Add(new TelemetryTrace
            {
                Key = key,
                Data = data,
                SeverityLevel = severityLevel
            });
        }
    }
```

A new event, which is just a dictionary, is inited by the middleware and a log it added to it. The middleware then awaits the response from the pipeline, during this time the API controller will add other logs to the event, and then the status code is added to the event and the event is sent when the pipeline returns to the middleware.

However I've noticed that if I add the `telemetryService` as a scoped or transient service the dictionary that holds the log data is set back to null after `await _next(context)` has been called.

This makes sense for transient, but with the definition of scoped being `Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests.` I expected that my dictionary state would be kept. But that only occurs with a singleton. Why isn't this happening the way I'm expecting?